How to list a tree of webpage files given url
I can use wget --mirror url to download a webpage, but how can I only list (see) a tree directory of that page in linux terminal?
For example I have a personal website where there is a .htaccess file Options +Indexes but I want to see it for other pages.
Q: How can I list a tree of files and directories for a given URL on linux?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
